# $\chi^2$ test for significance of a logistic regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, chi-squared-test

From "Thirty Years Training Rural Physicians" by Wendling et al. in *Academic Medicine* (https://journals.lww.com/academicmedicine/FullText/2016/01000/Thirty_Years_Training_Rural_Physicians__Outcomes.34.aspx):

> The overall logistic regression model including factors impacting
>   rural practice choice was statistically significant, $\chi^2(4, N =
>  2,344) = 142.3$, $P < .001$.

I'm struggling to understand what is actually being tested here with this $\chi^2$ test statistic. Is this supposed to be some sort of a [deviance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)) test?

Comment: Yes, it's a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: @COOLSerdash If it's a likelihood ratio test, when doing a deviance test, isn't there usually another model that you're comparing this model to?

Comment: Yes, they are comparing the model containing all variables to a model containing only the intercept. The difference in the degrees of freedom is $4$ in this case.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Oh, thanks. Not at all what I expected. Usually when I've seen a deviance test performed, it's usually on a few models that one would expect to fit data with - not something as drastic as intercept-only versus adding four variables in. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thanks. This is sometimes also called an [omnibus test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_test#Omnibus_Tests_in_Logistic_Regression).

Comment: @COOLSerdash I guess, from a practical standpoint - if one is wise about selection of explanatory covariates, wouldn't one expect a deviance test of a model with one or more covariates versus an intercept-only model to be "statistically significant" anyway?

Comment: $p$-values are also a function of sample size. In small samples, even "reasonable" covariates may fail to reach statistical significance (how one sould interpret that is another question). Ultimately, your question touches on a controversial topic that is [currently heavily debated](https://www.nature.com/magazine-assets/d41586-019-00857-9/d41586-019-00857-9.pdf): How and when are significance tests meaningful, if at all? Also, there are many different goals in model building and inference can certainly be one of them.